# zsh .zprofile / .zlogin not being sourced on gdm login?

Tags: shell, zsh, login, profile, gdm

I have noticed that `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zlogin` are only loaded (in my computer) when I use a login shell, but when I login with `gdm`, they are not run; `~/.profile` is ran instead. Is this normal?

Comment: Wayland-session?

Comment: Like Arpit Agarwal (1st commenter of the question) said, the question is a duplicate of [this other question][1]. Marking this as solved. [1]:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360134/why-gnome-display-manager-always-read-profile